# Getting a value from web call in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to get the returned value from a PHP script in Swift. However, it seems as though I keep getting the error:

> Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Here is the class:

```
var value: String!

func run(idNumber: Int) {
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://mywebsite.com/file.php")!)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    let postString = "a=Hello"
    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
        data, response, error in

        if error != nil {
            //answer = error;
        }

        let answerString = String(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
        self.value = answerString
    }
    task.resume()
}

func getValue() -> String{
    return value
}
```

The error occurs when calling the `getValue()` function. However, when I print out the "answerString" as soon as it is created, it prints out successfully!

The functions are called here:

```
let access = ApiAccess()
access.run(idNumber: 0)
print(access.getValue())
```

Comment: Where is the code that calls `getValue()`?

Comment: @JohnEllmore I apologize for the missing code. I have edited the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making a request is an asynchronous task. You need to wait the closure callback to be call before calling `getValue`.

You can add a closure callback to your `run` method. That way you will know when the request has finished and you can print the result:

```
var value: String!

func run(idNumber: Int, @escaping callback: () -> Void) {

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://mywebsite.com/file.php")!)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    let postString = "a=Hello"
    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
        data, response, error in

        if error != nil {
            //answer = error;
        }


        let answerString = String(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
        self.value = answerString
        callback()

    }
    task.resume()

}

func getValue() -> String{
    return value
}

let access = ApiAccess()
access.run(idNumber: 0) {
   print(access.getValue())
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the callback for `URLSession.shared.dataTask()` happens asynchronously, so you'll end up executing `access.getValue()` before your `var value` is ever set. This means that `value` is forcefully unwrapped before it has a value, which causes this error.

To workaround this, consider using promises, RxSwift, or similar async tools so that you only access values when available.

Answer (score 1):

Refactor your `run(idNumber:)` function to take a completion handler:

```
func run(idNumber: Int, completion: (String?, Error?)-> Void ) {
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://mywebsite.com/file.php")!)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    let postString = "a=Hello"
    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
        data, response, error in

        if error != nil {
           completion(nil, error)
        }
        let answerString = String(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
        self.value = answerString
        completion(answerString, nil)
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

And call it like this:

```
let access = ApiAccess()
access.run(idNumber: 0) { result, error in
    guard let result = result else {
      print("No result. Error = \(error)")
      return
    }
    print("result = \(result)")
}
```

(Or use Futures or Promises, as mentioned by @JohnEllmore in his answer)